# google scholar has not listed me as coauthor

Tags: google-scholar, preprint, indexing

After finally getting an article listed on google scholar via preprints, Google Scholar has not listed me as an author on my paper on either preprint it has indexed. I was the one who uploaded them to the preprint sites and I am the second author but they have only listed the first and third author and have not listed me.  How do I change or have this edited. And how does something like this even happen in the first place

Comment: Google scholar is full of bugs. Why do you care?

Comment: cause it took me three years to get this article on google scholar now I am omitted. how does that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to speak on behalf of Google here. The best idea is probably to contact them directly [1].

Before you do that, however, I would encourage you to double check if the details on the websites where your paper is published are correct. Much of what Google Scholar does is just indexing those websites and taking their data from there. Google explicitly recommends to ask for corrections there and not on Google Scholar. They also say state that an update to any details might take quite a bit of time, in the order of months [2]. So any recent correction to details on the publisher's side might not be updated yet.

[1] https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general

[2] https://scholar.google.com/intl/de/scholar/help.html#corrections

Comment: thanks. I was told by everyone it was impossible to contact google scholar as they had no support. I searched and searched and couldn't find any contact info myself. I was even told in a google forum by a google moderator they had no support. I don't know where you found the link to contact them but many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the first or third author. I *think* (but am not certain) that if Scholar has put them on it, they will then be able to edit the listing.

As to how it happens... ask Google? They won't tell you, though.

Comment: I am the only one listed as administrator on the preprint and I cannot edit indexed articles on google scholar where I am  the first author so highly doubtful, that my coauthors  would be able to do anything about it. Is there a way to contact Google Scholar directly?